# Unwanted behavior with List Partition function in which it strips out Iconized elements of Rules

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, grid-layouts, partitions, iconize

The goal is to output a `Grid` of sorted columns of `Rule` elements that are `Iconize`-d. The `List` elements are already sorted. The function `partition` is designed to partition down columns (not across rows) and works fine except for stripping out the `Iconize`. I have worked on this all day to no avail. Please help me spot the cause and if possible suggest a fix. Thank you.

```
ClearSystemCache[];
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(* this is the part that needs attention *)
(* unwanted behavior - strips out Iconize *)

partition[list_, prt_, len_] := Module[{
    col = If[IntegerQ[prtgrd] && prtgrd >= 1, prtgrd,
      If[MatchQ[prtgrd, Automatic | True],
       Which[len <= 18, 1, len <= 36, 2, len <= 54, 3, len <= 72, 4, 
        len <= 90, 6, True, 7], 1]],
    n
    },
   n = Ceiling[Length[lst]/col];
   Grid[Transpose@(PadRight[#, n, "0"] & /@ Partition[lst, UpTo[n]]) /. 
     "0" -> Nothing]
   ];

(* data *)

lst = {"SortByKeys" -> Automatic, "StyleKeys" -> Automatic, 
   "StyleValues" -> Automatic, "IconizeLongRules" -> Automatic, 
   "PartitionGrid" -> Automatic, "IconizeGrid" -> False, 
   "OutputMethod" -> Echo, Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}, 
   AllowedDimensions -> Automatic, AllowScriptLevelChange -> True, 
   AutoDelete -> False, Background -> None, 
   BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
   DefaultBaseStyle -> "Grid", DefaultElement -> "\[Placeholder]", 
   DeleteWithContents -> True, Dividers -> {}, Editable -> Automatic, 
   Frame -> None, FrameStyle -> Automatic, ItemSize -> Automatic, 
   ItemStyle -> None, Selectable -> Automatic, Spacings -> Automatic, 
   StripOnInput -> False};

prtgrd = Automatic;
ico = Iconize /@ lst
len = Length[lst];

(* runs *)

partition[ico, prtgrd, len]
```

Comment: Your code for the definition of `partition` uses `lst` directly, not the argument `list` of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n = Ceiling[Length[list]/col]` instead of `n = Ceiling[Length[lst]/col]`

```
ClearAll[partition];
partition[list_, prt_, len_] := Module[
    {
    col = If[
        IntegerQ[prtgrd] && prtgrd >= 1,
        prtgrd,
        If[
            MatchQ[prtgrd, Automatic | True],
            Which[
                len <= 18, 1,
                len <= 36, 2, 
                len <= 54, 3, 
                len <= 72, 4,
                len <= 90, 6,
                True, 7
            ]
            , 1
        ]
    ],
    n
    },
    n = Ceiling[Length[list]/col];
    Grid[
        Transpose[PadRight[#, n, "0"] & /@ Partition[list, UpTo[n]]] /. {"0" -> Nothing}
    ]
]
```

Comment: Nice catch!!! I was calling out the wrong variable. I should start using a smarter naming scheme. Thank you so much. :)